# Points that do not satisfy the Lebesgue Differentiation Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Lebesgue's differentiation theorem states that for any $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$
$$
\lim_{r->0} \frac{1}{|B_r(x)|} \int_{B_r(x)} f = f(x)
$$
for almost all $x\in \mathbb{R^d}$. This means that the set of points where the limit may not be exist or not equal f(x) if it exists has measure zero. Therefore, one may find a point $x_0 \in \mathbb{R^d}$ such that the limit
$$
\lim_{r->0} \frac{1}{|B_r(x_0)|} \int_{B_r(x_0)} f \neq f(x_0)
$$

For instance, if $A = [0,1]$ and $\chi_A$ denotes the characteristic function of $A$, then $\chi_A \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ and by Lebesgue's differentiation theorem,
$$
\lim_{r->0} \frac{1}{2r} \int_{x-r}^{x+r} \chi_A(t)dt = \chi_A(x)
$$
for almost all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. But, when $x=1$
$$
\lim_{r->0} \frac{1}{2r} \int_{1-r}^{1+r} \chi_A(t)dt = \lim_{r->0} \frac{1}{2r} \int_{1-r}^{1} \chi_A(t)dt = \lim_{r->0} \frac{1}{2r}r = 1/2.
$$

**My question:** Can we find a point where the limit value will be 1/2 for each function $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R^d})$?

Comment: If you take a function $f \in L_1(\mathbb R^d)$ such that $\|f\|_{\infty} < \frac{1}{2}$ then what happens?

Comment: The "therefore one can find $x_0$..." is wrong; the exceptional set of measure zero can be empty. (For example if $f$ is continuous with compact support.)